# Are self-hosted videos a good idea?

Tags: videos, vimeo

I was wondering if I should use a service like Vimeo or instead choose to host my video on my server ? 
I built a family website: it's password-protected, not indexed by search engines, etc. It would be nice to have videos there too but I can't decide which way to go.

Self-hosted videos

- Respect privacy
- I have plenty of space on my server (65GB)
- But I am concerned about bandwidth (they say it's unlimited but...)
- and about usability and ease of access for my family (they're not techies). They can't really use FTP and compress a video.
- Not sure there is a really good plugin for it

Vimeo

- Easy to add videos and get the embed code
- We can set a password for videos
- But I don't want to go Pro
- And you can't get HD quality with embedded videos.

As I said, plenty of disk space, supposedly unlimited bandwidth but non-techie family. I guess we'll want to display videos from few seconds to 5 minutes max. But those videos may be in HD. 
Which way should I go ? Any plugin recommendation.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather subjective but here is my view.

I have built video galleries used on public and private servers. I use Miro for compression in open source formats and video.js to support embedded viewing. Miro does a great job of minimizing bandwidth consumption. video.js has been more than adequate; I consider it a very good module. Together, they avoid stepping on copyrights of commercial vendors.

As an aside, IMHO public services like vimeo are great but not a wise choice for copyright protected intellectual property. Is your family info, images and videos "intellectual property"? Well, yes, I suspect it is until someone puts it on facebook et al.

Comment: video.js seems a good option. But you still have to upload video file (either via FTP or via the WordPress media uploader) and retrieve its url. I'm afraid they won't be able to do so.
I guess I'll stick with Vimeo for now with password protected videos... 

I ran some tests with video.js and I wasn't able to stream the video correctly, it didn't load. Which presets do you use with Miro ?

Comment: Re: upload issue; your choice, of course. OTOH, it is relatively simple to craft a script that accepts the upload path, runs the file through the Miro server app, and generates a post on your page.

Comment: One thing to check on streaming video is the allowed file types. The Apache AddType directive allows you to do this. I add video/ogg .ogv, video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v, audio/ogg .ogg .oga, and audio/mp4 .m4a.

Comment: For Miro, I produce Ogg Theora (.ogv) and WebM. I also generate mp4 as a fall back, e.g. Internet Explorer has given me grief. Here the code snippet I use for presentation: [http://pastebin.com/8EmJFJGu](http://pastebin.com/8EmJFJGu)

Comment: Wow really useful informations. You may have changed my mind about all that. I could write a script without much difficulty, I didn't know Miro had a server app and thought you were talking about Miro Video Converter on a desktop machine. Where can I find more infos about it? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, Miro is a desktop app. Sorry about the misdirection. Miro is built upon FFMpeg, see ffmpeg.org. FFMpeg is widely used in apps and services, including some of the big PAAS vendors. There are also many examples of scripts you can use on your server to automate the process. Searching on "ffmpeg video converter server" yielded 500K hits. I would not be at all surprised to find a WordPress or Joomla plugin that handles the whole process.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, Wyck, brasofilo, Michael, Johannes Pille; I am not familiar with the criteria for closing a question and so don't mean to cross a line here. Nonetheless, I believe this question did evolve into a properly technical thread.